# Prove that for all integers m, n, and d, if (m mod d) = (n mod d), then d|(m − n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that for all integers m, n, and d, if (m mod d) = (n mod d), then d|(m − n)

Direct proof:

Step1- (m mod d) - (n mod d) = 0

Step2- (m-n) mod d = 0

Step3- (m-n) = dx + 0

Step4- (m-n) = dx

Step5- d|(m-n)

QED

Is this good enough for a formal proof?

From step2 to step3, I used

$$(ndiv d = q) and (n mod d) = r$$ $$\iff n=dq+r$$

n div d = the integer quotient obtained when n is divided by d, and

n mod d = the nonnegative integer remainder obtained when n is divided by d.

Comment: Most commonly mod is defined as an equivalence relation, $n \equiv m \pmod{d}$, meaning $d \vert m - n$, exactly what you are trying to prove.  But your proof looks fine with the definitions you are using.

Comment: Logically yes it is correct. To be formal you should not use notation like $m\pmod{d}=n\pmod{d}$ and your step $1$ should be your step two directly.